# Recursively call a directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my directive:

```
ngjoola.directive('configItem', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: '/templates/configItem.html'
  };
});
```

This is my template:

```
<div ng-if="configValue.type == 'string'" class="form-group">
  <label for="{{configValue.key}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{configValue.name}}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="{{configValue.key}}" id="{{configValue.key}}" ng-model="configValue.value" placeholder="{{configValue.key}}" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="configValue.type == 'boolean'" class="form-group">
  <label for="{{configValue.key}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{configValue.name}}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{configValue.key}}" id="{{configValue.key}}" ng-model="configValue.value" placeholder="{{configValue.key}}"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="configValue.type == 'int'" class="form-group">
  <label for="{{configValue.key}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{configValue.name}}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="{{configValue.key}}" id="{{configValue.key}}" ng-model="configValue.value" placeholder="{{configValue.key}}" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="configValue.type == 'object'" class="form-group subConfig"><strong>{{configValue.name}}</strong>
  <div ng-repeat="(configKey, configValue) in configValue.value">
    <config-item></config-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically I have a nested JSON object that can either contain `configValue.type` of `string`, `int`, `boolean` or `object`. If the type is an object, I would like to iterate over it again and again until I've iterated throughout the whole nested document.

Problem is that I don't know how to use the `ngRepeat` in a way that will allow me to do so. Currently I'm creating an endless loop since I'm reusing the `configKey` and `configValue`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Note: The compile function cannot handle directives that recursively
>   use themselves in their own templates or compile functions. Compiling
>   these directives results in an infinite loop and a stack overflow
>   errors. This can be avoided by manually using $compile in the postLink
>   function to imperatively compile a directive's template instead of
>   relying on automatic template compilation via template or templateUrl
>   declaration or manual compilation inside the compile function.

So basically what you need to do is, in your postLink function, iterate over `configValue.value`, if that is of the type object, and manually `$compile` and append to your template, the directive.

Something like:

```
angular.forEach(configValue.value, function(value, key) {
   var newScope = $scope.$new();
   newScope.configValue = value;
   var newElem = $compile('<config-item></config-item>')(newScope);
   element.append(newElem);
}
```